# Can't draw a concentric pie chart in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, pie-chart, donut-chart

I have the following data:

```
Phyla       V4         Fl
 <chr>     <dbl>      <dbl>

Proteobacteria  88.58    81.43  
Firmicutes  7.33    15.34   
Actinobacteriota    1.55    1.94        
Bacteroidota    2.20    1.25
```

I want to display the data using a concentric pie chart. I have a couple of trials:

```
mycols <- c("#eee0b1", "#da8a67", "#e63e62", "#0033aa")
ggplot(df, aes(x = 2, y = V4, fill = Phyla)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", color = "white") +
  coord_polar(theta = "y", start = 0)+
  geom_text(aes(y = Fl, label = V4), color = "white")+
  scale_y_continuous(breaks=min(df$Fl):max(df$Fl)) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = mycols) +
  theme_void()+
  xlim(0.5, 2.5)
```

This generates
[image]

So, I got only one column displayed.

The other trial used this:

```
pie(x=c(88.58,7.33,1.55,2.2),labels="",
col=c("#eee0b1", "#da8a67", "#e63e62", "#0033aa"))
par(new=TRUE)
pie(x=c(81.43,15.34,1.94, 1.25),labels=c("Proteobacteria","Firmicutes","Actinobacteriota", "Bacteroidota"),radius=.5,
    col=c("#eee0b1", "#da8a67", "#e63e62", "#0033aa"))
```

that generates this figure:
[image]

I do not know which is easier to fix to generate the concentric pie. I need to include the color legend and label each pie with the category name (V4, Fl) along with adding the values as percentages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may try this

```
df %>%
    pivot_longer(-Phyla, names_to = "type", values_to = "y") %>%
    ggplot(aes(x = type, y = y)) +
    geom_bar(aes(fill = Phyla), stat = "identity",
      color = "white", position = "fill", width=0.7) +
    coord_polar(theta = "y", start = pi/2) +
    geom_text(aes(y = y, group = Phyla, label = y),
      color = "white", position = position_fill(vjust=0.5)) +
    geom_text(aes(x = x, y = y, label = type),
      data = data.frame(x = c(2.5, 3.5), y = c(0, 0), type = c("V4", "Fl"))
    ) +
    scale_fill_manual(values = mycols) +
    scale_x_discrete(limits = c(NA, "V4", "Fl")) +
    theme_void()
```

- `pivot_longer` transforms your data from "wide" to "long", so that you can draw multiple columns.
- `position="fill"` in `geom_bar()` and `position_fill` in `geom_text()` will scale y value into [0,1], so that two columns are aligned.
- `vjust=0.5` in `position_fill` will display values to their corresponding areas.
- It is a little difficult to label the circle directly using x axis texts, but you can label them manually using `geom_text()` with a new `data.frame(x=c(2.5,3.5),y=c(0,0),type=c("V4","Fl"))`

[image: result]

Comment: It works but I need to adjust the displayed values to their corresponding areas, and add % to each value. Also, I need to label each circle with the column name (V4, Fl). I used geom_label_repel(data = df,
                   aes(y = type, label = paste0(y, "%")),
                   size = 4.5, nudge_x = 1, show.legend = FALSE) +  but this did not work
    Any recommednations please? Much thanks!

Comment: ( @Eman ) To add % to the value, use `label = paste0(value,"%")` inside `geom_text()`, to manually change legend order, use `scale_fill_manual(values = c(Proteobacteria="#0033aa",Actinobacteriota="#eee0b1",Bacteroidota="#da8a67",Firmicutes="#e63e62"))`.

Comment: That is great! I reversed the legend order using guides(fill = guide_legend(reverse = TRUE)). But the displayed values are overlapping and I need to display them clearly. I added nudge_x = 1 to geom_text but it did not work, also, I used geom_label_repel to extend the value position outside the chart, but I got an error. Any help, please. Again, much thanks!

Comment: you can rotate the pie chart through `coord_polar(theta = "y", start = 1.57)`, otherwise you may set the text position manually.